# How to install plug in for elasticsearch?

Tags: plugins, github, elasticsearch

I am facing lot of difficulties in installing plugin like _head and FileSystem River for the elasticsearch.
I try to install _head as i follow GitHub saying edit plugin.bat with `-install mobz/elasticsearch-head` but it throws error when i run this bat file wityh -install is not a command.

Could anyone please help me to install both the plugin, mentioning clear steps and if possible without using GitHub as i am not able to do anything with GitHub.

Thanks in Advanbce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to edit the plugin.bat file. You just need to execute it, passing `--install mobz/elasticsearch-head` as the parameters. Please note the need for the double-dash before install. Your example only shows a single dash. You can alternatively use `-i` with the single dash, if you would like. You can see a complete listing of valid commands/parameters by executing `plugin.bat -h`

Example (assumes you are in the bin directory of your elasticsearch installation):

```
plugin.bat --install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

or

```
plugin.bat -i mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

Comment: and how to install FileSystem River?

Comment: From the documentation http://www.pilato.fr/fsriver/ `plugin.bat --install fr.pilato.elasticsearch.river/fsriver/0.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

On **Windows 7** with **elasticsearch.2.4.0**:

```
elasticsearch\bin\plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

See ["Install & Running"](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) section on elasticsearch-head official documentation